# How to implement the Export to excel function in SAPUI5?

Tags: sapui5

I have one Table element and I would like to download this table data with the download to excel function. I am deploying it  locally so no backend implementation is possible ? Is this possible ?

Regards,
Mayank Saxena

Answer (score 1):

When the data comes from an oData service, then you can request the data in xlsx format by adding the parameter `$format=xlsx` to the URL. Just redirect the user to the oData-URL directly. It will appear to the user like a regular download.

You can redirect the user to a different URL with `sap.m.URLHelper.redirect(url,true);`

Answer (score 0):

Download to excel only works with backendimplementation.
You have to check you Backend Metadata for 
`sap:supported-formats="atom json"`. There must be something like xlxs. If you use a smarttable the download to excel button is shown automatically

Answer (score 0):

You can use the export function with the following config.

```js
exportType: new sap.ui.core.util.ExportTypeCSV({
          separatorChar: "\t" ,
          mimeType: "application/vnd.ms-excel" ,
          charset: "utf-8",
          fileExtension: "xls"
}),
```