# Minimum SAPUI5 version for Export to Excel in a List Report (FE)

Tags: sapui5, export-to-excel, sap-fiori

I am developing a List Report app, using FIORI Elements.  It should be capable of exporting the listed data to excel.  For this reason, I have added the "useExportToExcel": true in the manifest.  While testing it from the VS Code, since it is using latest SAPUI5 version, it is working fine.  Yet, once app was deployed, the button is not present.  I am assuming the issue is related version in the FES (currently running 1.52.18).
I understand that a button could be added and then [do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38351467/how-to-implement-the-export-to-excel-function-in-sapui5) but still I would like to leave it within the FE framework

Thanks and regards!

Comment: Is this helpful?: https://blogs.sap.com/2018/04/23/new-excel-export-functionality-available/

Comment: Thanks, only problem with that solution is that adaptation projects can only be created through BAS (WebIDE R.I.P.).  Customer does not have license for BAS, so I am using VS Code, but no adaptation can be created there, see https://answers.sap.com/questions/13200196/how-to-create-an-adaptation-project-in-vs-code.html

Answer (score 0):

You could also add an extension to your project on the ListReport.

Under webapp folder it should create a subfolder ext/controller and the file "ListReportExt.controller.js" in it. You can verify in the manifest.json for the extension configuration.

Then in the lifecycle method "onInit" of the js file, access your SmartTable object by ID.

Use the method setUseExportToExcel(true) of the SmartTable. This should do the trick!

```
onInit: function() {
   const oSmartTable = this.getView().byId(this.getView().getId() + "--table");
   oSmartTable.setUseExportToExcel(true);
}
```